# Is there a way to filter subdocuments in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I'd like to filter subdocuments from a database in CouchDB.  An example document in the database would be:

```
{
    "Things": {
        "Thing:1": {
            "Number":1
            "Type": "TI"
        },
        "Thing:2": {
            "Number":2,
            "Type": "TI"
        }
    },
    "Type": "TD"
}
```

Is it possible to create a view that filters the subdocs similarly to this?

```js
for(key in Object.keys(Things)) {
    return Things[key].Number == 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, quite easily with a map function.  For example

```
function (doc) {
   Object.keys(doc.Things).forEach(function(key) {
    if(doc.Things[key].Number === 2) emit(doc._id, 1);
   });
}
```

This works with CouchDB 2.3. Fauxton makes it super easy to create and test views.

The design doc would look something like this for the view _design/thing/_view/thing

```
{
  "_id": "_design/thing",     
  "views": {
    "thing": {
      "map": "function (doc) {\n   Object.keys(doc.Things).forEach(function(key) {\n    if(doc.Things[key].Number === 2) emit(doc._id, 1);\n});\n\n}"
    }
  },
  "language": "javascript"
}
```